# sql server 2008 pivot more than one column and dynamic column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have two tables. I write a query. Date is dynamic. I can select any date. `

```
select a.MP,a.CP,a.Frequency,a.Time,CONVERT(varchar(12),b.date,101) as 
EntryDate,b.actualtime from mpcp a, DailyData b 
where a.UserID=1 and a.MpCpId=b.MpCpId and 
CONVERT(varchar(12),b.EntryDate,101) between
CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE()-5,101) and 
CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE()+25,101)`
```

## Output

[image]

But i want output like 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that i am storing your result in one temp table and imaging data i created one data for your requirement

try this one whether it is useful or not

```
create table #piv
(
mp varchar(10),
cp varchar(10),
freq varchar(10),
time int,
entryd date,
acuralize int
)
insert into #piv values
('don','asper','da',30,getdate(),0),
('dwm','donl','da',10,getdate(),3),
('qar','qpr','da',15,getdate(),5),
('qar','qpr','da',15,'01-16-17',5),
('qar','qpr','da',15,'01-15-17',5),
('qar','qpr','da',15,'01-16-17',5)

SELECT * FROM #piv
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(entryd) From #piv Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')
Select  @SQL = '
Select *,' + @SQL + '
From #piv
 Pivot (max(time) For [entryd] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: accepting means just  you need to tick on right mark which is on left side of the answer :)..@PramodThakur

Comment: sorry but it is not showing to me  can you check once if possible ...@PramodThakur

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic pivot. A good example is available on this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/).

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(max)
    SELECT  @cols=ISNULL(@cols+',[','[')+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.EntryDate,101)+']'  
    FROM mpcp a, DailyData b 
    where a.UserID=1 and a.MpCpId=b.MpCpId and DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),b.EntryDate) BETWEEN -5 AND 25
    GROUP BY a.time

    SET @sql='
    SELECT * FROM (

        SELECT a.MP,a.CP,a.Frequency,a.Time,CONVERT(varchar(12),b.date,101) AS EntryDate,b.actualtime 
        FROM mpcp a, DailyData b 
        WHERE a.UserID=1 and a.MpCpId=b.MpCpId and  where a.UserID=1 and a.MpCpId=b.MpCpId and DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),b.EntryDate) BETWEEN -5 AND 25
  ) AS t 
  PIVOT (MAX(actualtime) FOR EntryDate IN ('+@cols+') )'
  EXEC(@sql)
```